# Is using innerHTML with shadowRoot safe?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, shadow-dom, javascript-security

I'm trying to find any info about security patterns related to using innerHTML with shadowDOM. I'm not a js security master, so maybe my question is silly...

I'm working with chrome extension and I need to use shadowDOM to isolate css for context script. In many tutorials of doing this, I found  the code like that:

```
someDiv.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<style>
...css
  </style>`;
```

So the question is: Is it safe?

Comment: No, it's the same as the main DOM so the [same concerns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) apply. Sanitize your html or use DOM construction (either manual or via a library/framework).

Comment: What you mean 'DOM construction'? Using new CSSStyleSheet() with addRule? And how this can be dangerous if you set there only css classes?

Comment: 1) document.createElement('style'), 2) I've linked the article in MDN that explains the danger. If you fully control your html it is already sanitized.